# What is causing floating-point-to-unsigned conversion discrepancies here?

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

If I run this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    double a = -2.0;
    const double b = -2.0;
    using std::cout;

    cout << "Direct cast double -> uint16:\n";
    cout << "a1: " << static_cast<std::uint16_t>(a) << "\n";
    cout << "b1: " << static_cast<std::uint16_t>(b) << "\n";
    auto a2 = static_cast<std::uint16_t>(a);
    auto b2 = static_cast<std::uint16_t>(b);
    cout << "a2: " << a2 << "\n";
    cout << "b2: " << b2 << "\n";

    cout << "Indirect cast double -> uint16:\n";
    cout << "a3: " << static_cast<std::uint16_t>(static_cast<std::int16_t>(a)) << "\n";
    cout << "b3: " << static_cast<std::uint16_t>(static_cast<std::int16_t>(b)) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following results:

GCC x86-64:

```
Direct cast double -> uint16:
a1: 0
b1: 0
a2: 0
b2: 0
Indirect cast double -> uint16:
a3: 65534
b3: 65534
```

Clang x86-64:

```
Direct cast double -> uint16:
a1: 540684641
b1: 540684642
a2: 540684897
b2: 540684898
Indirect cast double -> uint16:
a3: 65534
b3: 65534
```

My questions are:

- Which convertions are implementation-defined here? I know floating points have limited accuracy but I would never expect `a1`, `b1`, `a2` and `b2` to be 4 different values. This looks like a compiler bug to me, especially given the fact that `2^16 = 65536`.
- What are maximum allowed differences between different compilers and platforms for this program? The code originates from production code where we discovered significant differences in values when the code was run on a different platform.
- Why inserting additional (intermediate) cast changes the result? Does introduction of intermediate type changes semantics (meaning of code) in the case of `a3` and `b3`?

https://godbolt.org/z/K4njaKT7c

Comment: You are casting unrepresentable values, I would not except anything sane to happen no matter what C++ standard technically guarantees. Casting to signed integer is IMHO undefined behaviour, unsure about unsigned case.

Comment: @Quimby "Casting to signed integer is IMHO undefined behaviour". I strongly doubt it. It should be implementation-defined or unspecified at worst. No static cast should result in UB.

Comment: @Xeverous https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast - search for "undefined". I too would like less UB in the standard, yet here we are. [Clang thinks this is undefined too](https://godbolt.org/z/z7aK5Pjh4).

Comment: @Xeverous Oops, sorry, I am wrong in your particular example, I misred the order of signed->unsigned for a3,b3, they should be fine in this case.

Comment: @Quimby a lot of UB does help the compiler to optimize. And implementing a "wrap around" conversion from `double` to `uintX_t` can be quite costly, especially if the value does not fit into any integer type supported by the hardware. If you want defined behavior, you can manually implement a conversion anyway you like.

Comment: Classic **undefined behavior** (UB).  UB makes any observed behavior allowed behavior.  If you want to make sure the value is in range, and handle the out of range, you have to to write that yourself.  One of the tenets of C++.

Comment: Here is better godbold with UB sanitizer enabled: https://godbolt.org/z/4E58Gnjv1 (clangs finds UB gcc is not)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the standard (https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf, Sec 4.9, §1) you are causing undefined behavior:

> A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be
> represented in the destination type.

UB means anything can happen, the program is even allowed to output values which are not representable by `uint16_t` (such as 540684641).

Comment: Ok so by adding an intermediate cast to `int16_t` (which supports representation of negative values), the behavior is not undefined and then the convertion to `uint16_t` has well-defined semantics (intentional overflow). Right?

Comment: Yes, conversion to `int16_t` is possible, since `-2` fits into an `int16_t`. And conversion from signed integer to unsigned integer is defined to wrap-around.

Comment: UB sanitizer enabled on godbolt https://godbolt.org/z/4E58Gnjv1 (clangs finds UB gcc is not)

Comment: Re “UB means anything can happen”: The meaning of “undefined behavior” in the C++ standard is that the standard does not impose any requirements. It does not rescind or alter any requirements from other sources, so it does not mean anything can happen.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes the fact that quite unpredictable things happen is rather a consequence of compilers assuming the code is exempt of UB for performing reasonable optimisations. So let's say that with this particular lecture of the standard, anything can happen, even if the standard does not explicitly state so.

Comment: @aka.nice: Re “yes the fact that quite unpredictable things happen is rather a consequence of compilers assuming the code is exempt of UB for performing reasonable optimisations”: No, the behavior of compilers is predictable, not unpredictable. They are designed and engineered, and they operate mechanically. They may be arcane or opaque to people unfamiliar with them, but they are not unpredictable. That is the wrong lesson to be teaching students. Re “So let's say that with this particular lecture of the standard, anything can happen”: No, let us not say that, because it is false.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Quoting from §1.3.24:  "Permissible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, [...]". To me "unpredictable results" means anything can happen. E.g. clang will happily ignore `uint16_t something = static_cast<uint16_t>(-2.0);`, leaving `something` uninitialized. Of course, if you knew everything else that happens on the computer, the behavior is still predictable.

Comment: @chtz: What is permissible is different from what can happen. Permissible merely means it would not violate any rules of the standard. It does not mean it can actually happen. They are different words, they have different meanings, and they communicate different concepts to students. “Anything is permissible” is true. “Anything can happen” is false.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Of course, the behavior of compilers is predictable, i hope so! What is not so much predictable, is the behavior of our code whenever it contains UB, once the compiler applied some optimizations assuming UB-free code. Of course, the problem comes form our code, not from the compiler, nonetheless, the fact that the behavior is quite unpredictable is a consequence of those optimizations. Does that clarify?

Comment: @aka.nice: A predictable compiler generates predictable code, and code is executed mechanically, so its behavior is predictable. The twists and turns introduced by combinations of optimization with undefined behavior may be complicated, but they are not unpredictable. And this matters. Experienced programmers use knowledge of how programs misbehave to find bugs. If undefined behavior were unpredictable, you could not diagnose problems from the behavior. If any undefined behavior could cause a segment fault or a link error or incorrect output, you would not know what to go look for…

Comment: … But we do often know what to go look for. When there is a link error, we do not go looking for an array overrun. When there is a segment fault, we do not go looking for multiple definitions of a symbol. Both of those have undefined behavior as specified by the C standard, but the behaviors are predictable. So telling students undefined behavior is unpredictable sends them the wrong message. It tells them you cannot debug because there is no logical connection between the source code and the behavior. That is false and harmful.

Comment: @EricPostpischil the behaviour is mostly unpredictable by a human, whatever the repeatability of underlying machinery. It's sensitive to the compiler used, to the compiler options, to the surrounding instructions, etc... Typically, the outcomes of exact same sentence might be different depending on surrounding instructions. Instrumenting the code with printf for example, might change the behaviour yet again... And the consequence of UB might more often than not be a silent corruption of our data, which origin might be less obvious to find than an immediate failure like a SEGFAULT...

Comment: @aka.nice: Re “the behaviour is mostly unpredictable by a human”: And that is a different statement from “The behavior is unpredictable.” It is still not true, because humans can learn and acquire skill and become good at predicting. And that is important. “The behavior is unpredictable” tells a student you cannot learn what happens, there is no use to it, do not bother trying to learn. “The behavior is hard to predict” means you can learn, it is useful to learn about compilers, optimization, linking, program loading, operating systems, and more…

Comment: … And now you have acknowledged “The behavior is unpredictable” is false. You have proposed a different sentence with the same word in it. Why bother? There is no need to feel an attachment to that word. It is not appropriate. Students should learn what happens “behind the curtain” so they develop full understanding of program execution. They should not think it is an opaque incomprehensible mystery.